# I wanted to know what all i should put in in the bottom of a bearded dragon tank

Tags: bearded-dragon, bedding

I am buying a bearded dragon and have never had a reptile before I wasn't sure what to use on the bottom of the tank I was just gonna use reptile sand only but i wasn't exactly sure what to put.

Comment: Welcome to pets.se Bailey! Your question has already been answered, it is located in the link provided.